why max-width not working on table with width of 100% and layout of fixed?
I created an HTML table with four columns. I want the third column to have a maximum width of 50px. However, the column width is not being applied as expected.
The table should take up 100% of the width of the container, with a fixed layout. Despite setting max-width: 50px for the third column, it seems to be ignored.
What might be causing this, and how can I fix it?
Here’s my code:
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table {
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;         
                border-right: 1px solid black;         
                border-collapse: collapse;  
                table-layout: fixed;
                width: 100%;
            }
            table td, table th {    
                border-left: 1px solid black;         
                border-top: 1px solid black;              
                border-bottom: none;    
                border-right: none;
            }
            table td:nth-child(3), table th:nth-child(3) {
                max-width: 50px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
                <th>Col4</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>88</td>
                    <td>888888888888</td>
                    <td>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</td>
                    <td>88888888</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>AA</td>
                    <td>AAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
                    <td>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</td>
                    <td>AAAAAAAA</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>


The max-width property does not work effectively for columns in a table when table-layout is fixed is applied. So for that you have to assign width:50px instead of max-width in table row and table header css


<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table {
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;         
                border-right: 1px solid black;         
                border-collapse: collapse;  
                table-layout: fixed;
                width: 100%;
            }
            table td, table th {    
                border-left: 1px solid black;         
                border-top: 1px solid black;              
                border-bottom: none;    
                border-right: none;
            }
            table td:nth-child(3), table th:nth-child(3) {
                width: 50px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
                <th>Col4</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>88</td>
                    <td>888888888888</td>
                    <td>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</td>
                    <td>88888888</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>AA</td>
                    <td>AAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
                    <td>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</td>
                    <td>AAAAAAAA</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>



